# listUsers is not a function error in Firebase Authentication

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to fetch a list of all the users in my web app, but I keep receiving this error:
"TypeError: *utils_firebase_WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2*_.auth.listUsers is not a function"

I copied exactly from Firebase documentation, and below is my code.
auth prints out "AuthImpl {app: FirebaseAppImpl, heartbeatServiceProvider: Provider, config: {…}, currentUser: null, emulatorConfig: null, …}", so I know that auth exists.

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { auth } from "../utils/firebase";

function users() {
  const listAllUsers = (nextPageToken) => {
    console.log(auth);
    auth
      .listUsers(1000, nextPageToken)
      .then((listUsersResult) => {
        listUsersResult.users.forEach((userRecord) => {
          console.log("user", userRecord);
        });
        if (listUsersResult.pageToken) {
          listAllUsers(listUsersResult.pageToken);
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("Error listing users:", error);
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    listAllUsers();
  }, []);

  return <div>users</div>;
}

export default users;
```

Can someone help me with this? Thanks!

I tried to look at the documentation from Firebase, but with no luck

Answer (score 1):

[`listUsers()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/firebase-admin.auth.baseauth#baseauthlistusers) is a method from the [Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin) and not from the [JS SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth). The [page you copied the code from](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#list_all_users) documents the **Admin SDK methods** for the Authentication Service.

There isn't any corresponding method in the JS SDK because, for security reasons, it is not possible to let a user directly listing all users of a Firebase project from a front-end.

If you want to list all users of your Firebase project from your front-end you can write a [Callable Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) that uses the [`listUsers()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/firebase-admin.auth.baseauth#baseauthlistusers) Admin SDK's method. It's then up to you to verify who can call this Cloud Function.